# Is it possible to call excel add in method using Excel JavaScript API programming?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, excel, office-interop

> I have one web application and i need to open one excel using jquery
>   and need to call one COM visible method in excel add in.
>   
>   Excel add-in is created using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
>   
>   Method to call :

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class AddinUtilities: IAddinUtilities
{
    public void PassGuidToAddIn(string guid)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(guid);
        List<Filters> filters = CommonDAL.GetFilters(new Guid(guid));
        if (filters != null && filters.Count > 0)
        {
            Helpers helper = new Helpers();
            helper.SetSlicers(filters);
        }
    }
}
```

> I need to implement cross browser solution for the same.

Comment: How could that COM add-in ever be loaded in a browser?